# Transformar div's em input e validá-las em um formulário

Tags: php, html

Tenho uma div com o atributo `contenteditable="true"`, que abre caixa de texto para podermos escrever diretamente na div, certo, até aí tudo bem, só que tipo, eu queria usar essa div como um input num formulário, eu não queria usar o input mesmo sabe, e sim a div fazendo essa função, só que acontece que eu não consigo pegar o valor dessa div com o método post do php.

```
<form action="post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div contenteditable="true"></div>
     <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Eu sei que daria para fazer isso com Jquery ou JS, porém apenas queria saber se teria como fazer diretamente com php, se alguém souber por favor. Mas se não tiver como vou fazer com Jquery mesmo... Vllw

Comment: Cara pq vc não faz isso usando uma `<textarea>` e não uma div? Por vc precisa tanto que seja uma div?

Comment: Por que preciso que o elemento vá crescendo juntamente com o texto enquanto ele é digitando, como o facebook, quando está sendo feita uma publicação e vai digitando ele vai crescendo, e com textarea aparece a barra de rolagem, e não consegui fazer ele crescer com jquery por que ainda não entendo bem sobre as funcões de altura do jquery. Já com a div quando ela vai sendo digitada ela já vai crescendo junto.

Comment: Com textarea você consegue obter esse mesmo comportamento usando `overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;` e manipulando o elemento com js para quando atingir todo o conteúdo visualizável, ele aumentar o tamanho, [aqui um exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/JShpZ/378/)

Answer (score 3):

Como [respondido por @Andrew Jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666484/how-to-submit-a-div-value-in-a-form) em outra pergunta.

> Only form elements are posted back to the server.

Somente os elementos do formulário são enviados para o servidor. Dessa forma, a melhor maneira de você fazer o que deseja é, criar um `input` do tipo `hidden` e através do `javascript` na hora de fazer o `submit`, pegar o texto da div e passar para o input criado.